# i am unable to read large xlsx in spout php

Tags: php

i have a large xlsx file having approx 24 MB size. It takes too much time even i have to read first row only.  If spout read each row one by one then why it takes too much time evenif i have to read first row only ?

Following is a complete code

```
require_once 'src/Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php'; 
$file_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'spout'.'/'.'testdata.xlsx';
use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);

try {
    //Lokasi file excel       
    $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX); //set Type file xlsx
    $reader->open($file_path); //open the file          

    $i = 0; 

    /**                  
    * Sheets Iterator. Kali aja multiple sheets                  
    **/           
    foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {   
        //Rows iterator                
        foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            echo $i."<hr>";
            if($i==0) // if first row
            {
                print_r($row); 
                exit; // exist after reading first row
            }
            ++$i;
        }       
        exit;
    }   
    echo "Total Rows : " . $i;              
    $reader->close();
    echo "Peak memory:", (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024), " MB";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;   
}
```

Can you help me what is reason regarding   this issue. How can i do it fast ? 
You can find test xlsx file at  http://www.mediafire.com/file/y369njsaeeah1ip/testdata.xlsx

**Excel file contains following content:**

- number of rows : 999991
- number of columns : 4  (i.e MPN,CATEGORY,MFG,Description)
- file size approx 24 MB and does not contain any formatting.
  [image]

Comment: I'd suggest you post some of your file in the body of the question, and/or maybe some information about it - number of rows/cols, etc. Nobody in their right mind is going to open a random Excel file from the internet.

Comment: Thanks for suggest. I have updated my question please check it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to store cell data with XLSX files:

1. the simplest one is to keep the cell values with the cells structure (i.e. cell "A1" contains "foo", "B1" contains "bar").
2. the other way to do it is by keeping track of the different values used in the spreadsheet and add a layer of redirection that will help removing duplicates: this translates to 2 files, one describing the structure (i.e. cell "A1" contains value referenced by ID1, "B1" => ID2, "C1" => ID1) and one describing the values (ID1 => "foo", ID2 => "bar").

The method 2 optimizes the size of the file since a value used N times will be stored only once (but referenced N times). However to read these values, you now need to read 2 files and have the mapping ready when you read the structure. Basically, in order to read the first row, you will read the structure to get the cells (A1, B1, C1) and then you need to resolve the values, using the IDs.

The inline method is more straightforward since everything is stored at the same place so you can read the structure and the values at the same time. No need for a mapping table.

Now back to your problem! The file you're trying to read is most likely using the method 2 (a file describring the spreadsheet's structure + a file containing all the values). When Spout inits the reader, it processes the file containing the values so that the mapping is ready whenever we start ready rows.

This processing can take a long time if there are a lot of values. Below a certain threshold (which depends on the amount of memory available), Spout loads the mapping [ID => value] into memory, which is pretty fast. However if there are too many values, Spout decides that everything may not fit into memory and caches chunks of the mapping on disk. This process is definitely time consuming...

So this is what's happening in your case. Hopefully that makes more sense now.
Eventually the threshold will be moved higher, as Spout is currently ultra defensive to avoid out of memory issues.